# URISyntaxException on underscore in path segment (not domain)

Tags: java, android

I got this exception a few times, and don't understand how it could be erroring about the underscore. I've searched around stackoverflow and the internet in general a bunch, but I haven't seen anything that would explain why I'm getting an error about the underscore that isn't in the domain.

Note: I can't reproduce it on purpose; I've tried passing the string `"https://11.111.1.111:1111/publicapi/v1/aaaaa/AAAAAa1aAAA1a11aaAaAA1aaa11AAAaaA1AAaAAA1aaA11A_aaaAaAaA1aaAaaaaaAAaa1Aa-Aa1AAAAAAA1Aa"` to `new java.net.URI(...)`, but it doesn't error.

note: I replaced sensitive uppercase alpha characters with 'A' and lowercase alpha characters with 'a', the url is the same as the one from the error otherwise.

```
Android: 4.4.4
Manufacturer: LGE
Model: Nexus 5
Date: Wed Nov 26 16:26:10 MST 2014

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 94: https://11.111.1.111:1111/publicapi/v1/aaaaa/AAAAAa1aAAA1a11aaAaAA1aaa11AAAaaA1AAaAAA1aaA11A_aaaAaAaA1aaAaaaaaAAaa1Aa-Aa1AAAAAAA1Aa
    at libcore.net.UriCodec.validate(UriCodec.java:63)
    at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:402)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
    at [redacted]._doRequestCore([redacted].java:205)
    ... [redacted] ...
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

[redacted]._doRequestCore line 205:

```
request.setURI(new java.net.URI(baseurl + relurl));
```

the types of the variables there are:

- `String baseurl`
- `String relurl`
- `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase request`

baseurl was `"https://11.111.1.111:1111/publicapi"`, and I can only assume that relurl must have been:

```
"/v1/aaaaa/AAAAAa1aAAA1a11aaAaAA1aaa11AAAaaA1AAaAAA1aaA11A_aaaAaAaA1aaAaaaaaAAaa1Aa-Aa1AAAAAAA1Aa"
```

The url is certainly already encoded, via something like this:

```
String relurl = android.net.Uri.parse("/v1/aaaaa/")
    .buildUpon()
    .appendPath("AAAAAa1aAAA1a11aaAaAA1aaa11AAAaaA1AAaAAA1aaA11A_aaaAaAaA1aaAaaaaaAAaa1Aa-Aa1AAAAAAA1Aa")
    .build().toString();
```

But that encode doesn't seem to encode the underscore to an escaped octet, just like I wouldn't expect it to. I looked at the appropriate version of UriCodec.java validate():63 - which calls abstract isRetained():

```
// https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/15a93894f19b27f3d85b8e3c3de8cff8a33964d3/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/UriCodec.java

public abstract class UriCodec {
    /**
    * Returns true if {@code c} does not need to be escaped.
    */
    protected abstract boolean isRetained(char c);
    /**
    * Throws if {@code s} is invalid according to this encoder.
    */
    public final String validate(String uri, int start, int end, String name)
            throws URISyntaxException {
        for (int i = start; i < end; ) {
            char ch = uri.charAt(i);
            if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                    || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
                    || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
->                  || isRetained(ch)) {
                i++;
            } else if (ch == '%') {
                if (i + 2 >= end) {
                    throw new URISyntaxException(uri, "Incomplete % sequence in " + name, i);
                }
                int d1 = hexToInt(uri.charAt(i + 1));
                int d2 = hexToInt(uri.charAt(i + 2));
                if (d1 == -1 || d2 == -1) {
                    throw new URISyntaxException(uri, "Invalid % sequence: "
                            + uri.substring(i, i + 3) + " in " + name, i);
                }
                i += 3;
            } else {
63:             throw new URISyntaxException(uri, "Illegal character in " + name, i);
            }
        }
        return uri.substring(start, end);
    }

...
```

but that's overridden by URI.java's PartEncoder member class to check UNRESERVED, which definitely has underscore in it:

```
// https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.4.4_r2/luni/src/main/java/java/net/URI.java

    static final String UNRESERVED = "_-!.~\'()*";

    ...

    static final UriCodec PATH_ENCODER = new PartEncoder("/@");

    ...

    private static class PartEncoder extends UriCodec {
        private final String extraLegalCharacters;
        PartEncoder(String extraLegalCharacters) {
            this.extraLegalCharacters = extraLegalCharacters;
        }
        @Override protected boolean isRetained(char c) {
->          return UNRESERVED.indexOf(c) != -1
                    || PUNCTUATION.indexOf(c) != -1
                    || extraLegalCharacters.indexOf(c) != -1
                    || (c > 127 && !Character.isSpaceChar(c) && !Character.isISOControl(c));
        }
    }
```

parseURI on line 402 is:

```
path = PATH_ENCODER.validate(uri, fileStart, queryStart, "path");
```

I did see that [this commit has been made](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/435edc3fa9abd3f8d324c9dd4279a165051052ba) to that file since android 4.4.4, but that only looks like it affects domains, not the path segment.

I just don't see how this could end up producing that exception, that url looks perfectly valid to me, and is working in further tests. Anyone see what I'm missing? I really don't like letting exceptions go due to not understanding. My only hypothesis was that there was a unicode character in the url that somehow managed to get stripped when reporting the exception - doesn't seem very likely.